# Dll still in memory after the program quits

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Maybe my question is totally wrong, but that's the first thing that comes to my mind.

So, I have two processes (two exes) - let call it **A** and **B**. Process **A** starts process **B** as detached process (with Qt's `QProcess::startDetached()`) in separate working directory. At some point **B** decides to update **A**. It sends a signal to it and **A** quits (with `QApplication::quit()`). After that **B** downloads files and tries to replace (unzip) them to **A**'s folder, but unzipping fails. The library I'm using for unzipping (*quazip*) doesn't have any errors - it just fails. One more interesting thing - some files in **A**'s folder are deleted during unzip process.

Here's a structure of my project:
**Process A**: `a.exe` uses `1.dll`, `2.dll`, `3.dll`
**Process B**: `b.exe` uses `1.dll`, `2.dll`

This dlls are the same but they are copied to the different folders - **A**'s and **B**'s folders. One of the dlls is used for communication via socket/server. Another dll uses extern variables (don't know - maybe it relates somehow).

The zip file have the same `a.exe`,`1.dll`, `2.dll`, `3.dll` files. **B** can't unzip some files to **A**'s folder but somehow old files in that folder became deleted. The zip file absolutely correct, according to task manager **A** is not running.

My operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: What is your question then? If you can't replace a file (DLL or otherwise) because it's locked by a process, that seems to explain things. There are a number of utilities available that show which process is locking a file.

Comment: Speculation only - but what if there is a manifest involved with path to the dlls so that folder A dlls also get used by b.exe? Or what if folder A is in the global search path? (The second should not happen as it should load from local dir first). Other speculations: Something wrong with the arguments to the unzip call. After terminating the process, the unzip is done before A.exe is completely terminated. The best sequence to prevent race condition is: 1. Trigger shutdown of A.exe. 2. WaitForSingleObject(<handle of a.exe process>,..) 3. Update

Comment: I'm not sure that dll is blocked by a process because that process killed. I need some ideas where should I search. Or can it be because of the same names of the dlls in **A** and **B** or because of work of `startDetached`.

Comment: @nikitablack As Roger Rowland suggested, find and use a utility to inspect those files to see if they're open by some process, and what that process is. That would answer the question implied by the title to this question: Is the DLL still open? This is an idea, try it, don't reject it.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, this is the first I tried. ProcessExplorer shows me that each process uses it's own copy of dll (the paths are different). But anyway, some dlls can't be replaced.